# Leaflet: remove legendControl onclick

Tags: javascript, leaflet, legend

I have a leaflet map that should be updated onclick. Everything works less remove the previous legend. I have searched similar questions but I have not found a solution for me.

So, while onclick if the legend is the same there is no problem, but if you choose the other legend, both appear. Never the same twice, but both when changing the legend option.

Here the JS

```
var legendPPs = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});


var legendRME = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});


submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  /* ---- */

  var currentLegend = L.control();

  // fileInfo.row capture what type of legend is to be displayed
  if (fileInfo.row.includes("pps") || fileInfo.row.includes("rrs") ) {
    map.removeControl(currentLegend);
    currentLegend = legendPPs;
    currentLegend.addTo(map);


  } else if (fileInfo.row.includes("rme")) {
    map.removeControl(currentLegend);
    currentLegend = legendRME;
    currentLegend.addTo(map);

  } else {
    console.log("No rate found")
  }

  /* --- */

});
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: After you add the first `L.control()` to the map you need to preserve the object to use later when you remove it. It looks like you're creating a new object every time.

Comment: That´s right. I have taken the var currentLegend out of the event and it works perfectly. Thank you!